# Help Installing a Font for Latex on Mac (map file, directory structure, font naming)

Tags: fonts

I'm sure this sort of thing has been asked again and again, but I cannot find a guide or post anywhere that has been able to get me what need. All the online help seems to be aimed at a higher level than I can cope with (no big surprise). So any help I could get here would be greatly appreciated

The font I'm trying to install is Gill Sans.

Although for Windows, this guide seems to be the most hand-holdy http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm, but can only take me so far

I have the font files in ttf, tfm, vpl, vf, pfb and afm formats, and am happy to use any to get the desired result. I'd like to think that it would just be a case of dropping the relevant files into the appropriate directories and being done, but as I understand it there are a few things preventing me from using the font in Latex - namely making/appending? the map file, having the right directory structure for fonts, and naming the fonts appropriately.

I'd be thankful for help with any of these problems. I should also add that I do not have the option of using XeTeX or any other 'non-standard' form of Latex.

Comment: If you file format list above is all you have it looks as if someone did only the first half needed to use the font with (pdf)latex. Beside this: as you have `pfb` and `afm` files you should use `fontinst` to create the rest. See the `fontinstallationguide`.

Comment: Are you able to install the font system-wide and view them in the Font Book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at possibly all of the guides on all of the internet ever, I found this guide which worked for me first time. I'd thoroughly recommend it. It is step-by-step and very easy to follow.

http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/latex/no-bs.html

Comment: Towards the end of the font installation I found myself having to use this guide to supplement the one above:
http://www.mamster.net/tex/latex-fontfaq-amster-burton.pdf